# How do I get LdapAttributes

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap, ldif

I'm trying to export ActiveDirectory records into LDIF-formatted files using Spring.

I'm finding lots of information about *parsing* LDIF files, but relatively little about exporting to LDIF. With Spring there is an `LdapAttributes` class whose `toString()` method returns a string in LDIF format, but I don't see where to get the `LdapAttributes` instance in the first place. I don't see anything on the `LdapTemplate`.

Hopefully the framework provides a simple way to get this, rather than my having to build the `LdapAttributes` object myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out something like the unboundid LDAP SDK https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldif/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I came up with this:

```
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;    
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.DistinguishedName;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapAttributes;

public class PersonMapper implements AttributesMapper {

    @Override
    public Object mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
        String dnValue = (String) attrs.get("distinguishedName").get();
        DistinguishedName dn = new DistinguishedName(dnValue);
        LdapAttributes ldapAttrs = new LdapAttributes(dn);
        for (NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> ne = attrs.getAll(); ne.hasMore(); ) {
            ldapAttrs.put(ne.next());
        }
        return ldapAttrs;
    }
}
```

I can't help but feel that there must be some more out-of-the-box way to do this, though the above works.

Answer (score 0):

```
LdapAttributes ldapAttributes = basic2LdapAttributes(result.getNameInNamespace(), result.getAttributes());

public static LdapAttributes basic2LdapAttributes(String distinguishedName, Attributes attributes) throws NamingException{
        LdapAttributes ldapAttributes = new LdapAttributes();
        ldapAttributes.setName(LdapUtils.newLdapName(distinguishedName));
        for (NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> nameEnumeration = attributes.getAll(); nameEnumeration.hasMore();) {
            ldapAttributes.put(nameEnumeration.next());
        }
        return ldapAttributes;
}
```